# Get donation from your android app

Tags: android, currency

I'm building an app with a friend, and even though we want our app to be free and without any advertising we would like to be able to receive some money from potential donners, how would I do that? is it possible to do it via the google dev app (I want it as simple as possible for the donor) or is the best way paypal?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way for the donor is of course to provide Google Play payment options.

The most popular way I've encountered for this kind of setup is **to have two applications**:

- Free,
- "Donate", which costs the amount of donation you wish to receive.

**An alternative** (simpler to manage, but may be less visible to your users depending on how you implement it) **is to use [In-App-Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html)**. That way you could just have one application with a "Donate" button.

**IMPORTANT:** this covers only the technical part of this problem, **for the legal part, you'd have to consult a lawyer**.

**At least some countries impose a tax on donations in those kinds of cases**, or require some additional paperwork to fill, so if you're unlucky or your app provides you significant income **you could be hit by your tax revenue service (or even the police, if not filling paperwork breaks some criminal laws)**.

Comment: thanks I'll have a look at it, and I don't think I'll generate such revenues that I'll get bothered by the law... :P

Comment: yes I was about to approve your answer that was very fast and accurate!

Comment: @zopa : great, thanks. I also meant accepting answers [for the other questions you posted](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2353731/zopa?tab=questions) - it's perfectly OK to accept your own answers, by the way.